In EF Core, is it ok to use entity instance in comparisons instead of primitives like Id when querying the database
Using Entity Framework Core, I have noticed it's possible to use entity instances for filtering and lookup in queries.
Examples:
dbContext.Foo.Where(o => o == instanceOfFoo).Include(....
dbContext.Bar.Where(o => o.Foos.Contains(instanceOfFoo)

I wonder what the downsides are by doing that? Or are there any downsides?

Questions about pros and cons are too broad and opinion-based, as described in What types of questions should I avoid asking?.

Having spent time writing EF Core extensions, I can tell you that yes, this is perfectly safe to do with a keyed class from your model, although it's probably slightly slower to compile the query. This is only a concern on the first run of the query usually.
EF Core has explicit handling for this situation, and it pulls out the primary key properties to compare against. This code is located in
RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor (the expression visitor that translates LINQ operators), in a function called TranslateContains.
It has the following behaviour:

Exactly one primary key column: translate to an IN on that column
Otherwise attempt to translate an EXISTS with a nested WHERE inner = outer, this is picked up in the TranslateAny function in the same class.

That would then move to RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor (the expression visitor that parses scalar comparisons and calculations), which picks up structural type equality in a function called TryRewriteStructuralTypeEquality. This then rewrites the equality taking into account the primary keys (thorwing an error if there is no PK).
So it's slower to compile, because there are more steps involved, but either you get a valid comparison or an error. In no circumstances does EF Core "pull back" the whole entity to the client-side to compare, as others have suggested. You also don't get extra joins, unless possibly there is an Owned Entity involved.
Either way, you can check the actual generated SQL using ToQueryString, this will confirm either way if the SQL is actually efficient.

Yes it is ok to use entity instance in comparisons instead of primitives like Id when querying the database. However, In Entity Framework Core, it's generally best practice to use primitive values (like IDs) for comparisons in queries rather than entity instances. In such case, If you already have retrieved value somewhere earlier in the code which could be reused in your comparison query then try to use the value instead of using entity instance. Here are a few reasons why:
Performance: Using primitive types, such as IDs, allows EF Core to translate queries more efficiently into SQL. When you compare entity instances, EF Core may need to evaluate the entire entity, which can lead slower the performance.
Clarity: Using IDs or simple values makes your code clearer. It’s easier to understand that you are comparing against a unique identifier rather than dealing with the intricacies of an entire entity object. We have separation of concerns.
Avoiding Issues with Tracking: When you use entity instances, EF Core's change tracking can complicate the query. If the context is tracking the instance, it might not behave as expected, particularly if the entity state changes.
var result = context.Entities
    .Where(e => e.SomeProperty == existingEntity.SomeProperty)
    .ToList();

In this case, if existingEntity is an instance of an entity, EF Core has to evaluate the property of the entire object, which can introduce complexity and may impact performance.
var result = context.Entities
    .Where(e => e.SomeProperty == existingEntityId)
    .ToList();

In this version, if you directly compare to a primitive value like existingEntityId, it's clearer and more efficient because you're working with a simple value rather than an entire object. For this you have to retrieve your primitive value earlier to use in the query.

This vas valuable insight, if it really is true. I would not have guessed there would be any difference when the comparison in both cases is done on a primitive.

Why clearer? Others, esp. the DDD crowd, will contend that comparing instances is clearer and less error-prone. Which only demonstrates that this is an opinionated question.

clearer because it reduces context dependency: Primitive comparisons do not require the reader to understand the state of the existingEntity object or whether it's being tracked. This can make the code easier to read, especially in larger codebases. For example, sometimes entity property value changes based on some business needs, if we compare independently, we will not be tied to entity state change. it can be handled separately. We have separation of concern. @Gert Arnold

"When you use entity instances, EF Core's change tracking can complicate the query" this is not true.  Change tracking only comes in if you actually select out the data, not if you are just comparing in a Where.
